# How to remove tags from my user page?

Tags: support, user-profile

There is currently tags on my Arqade profile that I have no intelligence in ([windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10), [controllers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controllers), and [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues)). Is it possible to remove them from here?

Comment: ironically, these tags appear on your user profile because your expertise in these subjects have been of more help to users than your other posts. Ultimately, I think you might be underestimating yourself, to say that you have "no intelligence" in these topics.

Comment: Sorta, but I looked up the answer for what I got those 4 upvotes and bounty from, so I could help that guy out because the other 2 answers wern't helpful.

Comment: As an alternative, you may want to add tags to your Favorites.  For example, I have Bloons-TD-5 in my favorites, so I can click from the front page directly to BTD5 questions.  Favorites are entirely your choice, so they don't need to be busy tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - these are just tags relating to posts you've made (I believe both questions and answers). It doesn't really affect anything - it just gives people an idea of the sort of stuff you've been involved in - as you post more, these will likely change to better reflect the stuff you are more knowledgeable about. :)

Comment: Really? I do go to find questions that I can answer by going to "my tags", but I get questions I can't answer a lot because of those tags. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @YoshiLikes You can go to the tags page and search for any tag you like to see things you know more about, perhaps?

Comment: I tried that, I just have certain things that I am really smart in - and ones I pretend to be. Unfourtainitly for me, the games I am smart with is inactive on this site... :(}